# Pass a value in @Url.Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to pass the id to the controller, the below code is sending null all the time so the action is not getting called(Action takes in an int value as parameter)

```
@foreach (var item in @Model) {
    <li id="@item.TemplateID">
        <a href="@Url.Action("Template_WorkFlowStageList", "Template", new { templateID = @item.TemplateID });">@item.Name <span>&raquo;</span></a>
    </li>
}
```

Error resolved, should'nt use semi column after url.action
Working Code:

```
    @foreach (var item in @Model) {
    <li id="@item.TemplateID">
        <a href="@Url.Action("Template_WorkFlowStageList", "Template", new { templateID = @item.TemplateID })">@item.Name <span>&raquo;</span></a>
    </li>
}
```

Comment: Show the controller `Template_WorkFlowStageList()` method. Does it have a parameter `int templateID`?

Comment: check your controller

Comment: Your code looks fine. Inspect the href attribute of the html your generating - it should be `href="/Template/Template_WorkFlowStageList?templateID=someValue"` (or `"/Template/Template_WorkFlowStageList/someValue"` if you have defined a route.

Comment: Is your controller located in inside of some area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error resolved, I shouldn't have used a semi column after `url.action`.
Working Code:

```
    @foreach (var item in @Model) {
    <li id="@item.TemplateID">
        <a href="@Url.Action("Template_WorkFlowStageList", "Template", new { templateID = @item.TemplateID })">@item.Name <span>&raquo;</span></a>
    </li>
}
```